# How to Properly Fine-Tune Translational Transformer Models

Tags: python, nlp, translation, huggingface-transformers

I want to fine-tune Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-ar for english to arabic translation, but the results are so bad, although I previously used Hugging Face Autotrain tool on smaller dataset, and got better results. My code is:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

import pandas as pd

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-ar")


model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-en-ar")

dff = pd.read_csv('/content/data.csv')



"""
# Formatting Data
"""

source = dff['eng_Latn'].values.tolist()
target = dff['arb_Arab'].values.tolist()


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
max = 512
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(source, target, test_size=0.2)
X_train_tokenized = tokenizer(X_train, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max, return_tensors="pt")
y_train_tokenized = tokenizer(y_train, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max, return_tensors="pt")
X_val_tokenized = tokenizer(X_val, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max, return_tensors="pt")
y_val_tokenized = tokenizer(y_val, padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=max, return_tensors="pt")

import torch
class ForDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, inputs, targets):
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.targets = targets
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.targets)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        input_ids = torch.tensor(self.inputs["input_ids"][index]).squeeze()
        target_ids = torch.tensor(self.targets["input_ids"][index]).squeeze()
        
        return {"input_ids": input_ids, "labels": target_ids}

train_dataset = ForDataset(X_train_tokenized, y_train_tokenized)
test_dataset = ForDataset(X_val_tokenized, y_val_tokenized)


from transformers import DataCollatorForSeq2Seq

data_collator = DataCollatorForSeq2Seq(tokenizer=tokenizer, model=model, return_tensors="pt")

"""# Metrics"""

import evaluate

metric = evaluate.load("sacrebleu")

import numpy as np


def postprocess_text(preds, labels):
    preds = [pred.strip() for pred in preds]
    labels = [[label.strip()] for label in labels]

    return preds, labels


def compute_metrics(eval_preds):
    preds, labels = eval_preds
    if isinstance(preds, tuple):
        preds = preds[0]
    decoded_preds = tokenizer.batch_decode(preds, skip_special_tokens=True)

    labels = np.where(labels != -100, labels, tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    decoded_labels = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels, skip_special_tokens=True)

    decoded_preds, decoded_labels = postprocess_text(decoded_preds, decoded_labels)

    result = metric.compute(predictions=decoded_preds, references=decoded_labels)
    result = {"bleu": result["score"]}

    prediction_lens = [np.count_nonzero(pred != tokenizer.pad_token_id) for pred in preds]
    result["gen_len"] = np.mean(prediction_lens)
    result = {k: round(v, 4) for k, v in result.items()}
    return result

"""# Training"""

from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer



training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(

    output_dir="mymodel",

    evaluation_strategy="epoch",

    save_strategy = 'epoch',

    learning_rate=2e-5,

    per_device_train_batch_size=16,

    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,

    weight_decay=0.01,

    save_total_limit=3,

    num_train_epochs=20,

    predict_with_generate=True,

    load_best_model_at_end=True

)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(

    model=model,

    args=training_args,

    train_dataset=train_dataset,

    eval_dataset=test_dataset,

    tokenizer=tokenizer,

    data_collator=data_collator,

    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,

)

trainer.train()

""" # Testing """

trainer.save_model('finalmodel')

from transformers import pipeline

mymodel = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("./finalmodel")

translator =  pipeline ('translation' , model = mymodel, tokenizer=tokenizer)

print (translator('suddenly, we were attacked '))

>>> [Some Bad translation]
```

A snippet of the metrics, where bleu ends up 0 after 10 epochs!:
[image]

The csv data looks like this:
[image]

I'm suspecting issues with the tokenizer maybe? Or is it the data not well formatted? Could it be the training arguments?

I'm new to NLP, thus, I copied a lot of code from SO and Hugging Face.

Comment: I'm looking at the same thing, have you figure it out yet?